# Using charAt() to change a char array

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm utterly boggled as to why `charAt()` works in some scenarios but not others. I am doing exercises while learning Java and one of them was to take a string, and return it in reverse order.

My working code:

```
public String reverseString(String tempStr){
    int initialindex = tempStr.length()-1;
    int reverseindex = 0;
    char tmp;
    char[] array = new char[tempStr.length()];

    for(int tempchar : array){
        tmp = tempStr.charAt(initialindex);
        array[reverseindex] = tmp;
        initialindex--;
        reverseindex++;
    }
    String returnstr = new String(array);
    return returnstr;
}
```

The problem I ran into is using the following `for` statement prints gibberish:

```
for(int tempchar : array){
    array[reverseindex] = tempStr.charAt(initialindex);
    initialindex--;
    reverseindex++;
}
```

There were perhaps a dozen different variants of using `while` loops, standard `for` loops and a few other versions of code that were ugly and didn't work. Why did my making a `char tmp` field, putting the inspected characrer in said field, and then using said field to enter the data into an array work?

Also, why am I unable to just return the string using `return array.toString();`?

Edit: I'm using the latest Eclipse I downloaded today, switched from netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I copied your code into my editor and it performed fine using either version, with `tmp` field or without. You must have made some other error using the other method.
2. Java doesn't support pretty `.toString()` for arrays; any object which does not override `toString` will produce the hashCode of the object rather than the contents/fields of the object, and arrays are no exception here. Whilst it might seem sensible for character arrays, the same operation on an int array would produce nonsense; See the difference between `Arrays.toString()` and `String.valueOf(array)`. In this case, you probably want to use the `String.valueOf` method.

Comment: Hmmm...I tried the other method and I am irked. It works now. In regards to the second answer, I had the value `[C@3956f14c` returned. Is that the hashCode of the object you mentioned?

Comment: Depending on the implementation, Object.toString()'s default function will return `this.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());` (or some similar variant). So I guess in this case, `[C` is 'array' (because they're kind of a special object) and `3956f14c` is the hashcode

Answer (score 0):

As a hint to get you started: if you want to convert a `char` array into a `String` use the `String` constructor that takes a `char` array.

Update: I see you already did that in your edit. Does it work as expected now?

Your loop looks a little bit weird since you never use your loop variable. you could try this:

```
char[] initialArray = initialStr.toCharArray();
char[] array = new char[tempStr.length()];

for(int srcIndex = 0, destIndex = array.length-1; destIndex >= 0; srcIndex++, destIndex--) {
    array[destIndex] = initialArray[srcIndex];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have used it. But at the time I felt like hammering a square peg in a round hole, so I just used blunt force to get it done. Bad practice, but my patience was wearing thin for a seemingly simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `array.toString()` return string representation of the object. You need to use char[] constructor of String `new String(array)` to create String from the char[].

Answer (score 0):

```
   public String reverse(String str)
        {
            if(str == null)
            {
               return null;
             }
           byte[] byteArray=  str.getBytes();
           int arrayLastIndex = byteArray.length -1 ;

           for(int i=0 ; i < byteArray.lenght/2: i++)
           {
              byte temp = byteArray[i];
              byteArray[i] = byteArray[arrayLastIndex -i ]
              byteArray[arrayLastIndex - i] = temp;
           }

           return new String(byteArray);
        }
```